# How to get the max row number of records by customer?

Tags: sql, group-by, max, ssms

I have a query in Microsoft sql server management studio 18 and I am trying to show the 5 most recent dates for each customer. Here is the query:

```
SELECT Customer, Plant, ForecastDate  FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Plant, ForecastDate  ORDER BY Customer DESC) as ROW_NUM 
FROM table
) AS T
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Here is the output of the query code above:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecofm.png)

This is what I would like the output to look like:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lEno.png)

Here is some [Consumable sample data](https://zumbiel.weebly.com/uploads/4/1/5/0/41508101/book4.xlsx)

I am dealing with weekly forecasts that my customers give to me that changes every week or so. I upload the data into a SQL server. I am trying to to compare and contrast the Quantity to other forecast dates. This is why I want the past 5 dates. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you want the *5* most recent dates, shouldn't the clause be `ROW_NUM <= 5`? Plus your `OVER` will need addressing to not be the "most recent" customer by Plant and date.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, but you also ned to change your `OVER` clause; otherwise you'll get the "top 5" customers per plant and date.

Comment: I want the 5 most recent dates for each customers, not just the 5 most recent dates. When the clause is ```ROW_NUM <= 5``` it gives me multiple rows that have the same date customer and plant. I just want to get the 5 most recent dates by customer. I have added what the desired output would look like in the original post

Comment: Did you alter the `OVER` clause, like i mentioned?

Comment: How should I alter it? I didn't follow what you meant by that

Comment: Presumably, with no sample data, you should be partitioning on the customer and ordering on the date.

Comment: This just gives me the most recent date for each customer and plant. I am trying to find the past 5 dates for each customer and plant.

Comment: Presumably you have multiple rows for the same customer on the same date then? Why would those 5 rows therefore not all be the rows you want? It's time for *consumable* sample data and expected results here.

Comment: I edited the op to include sample data and to explain what I am trying to do. Yes I have multiple rows  on the same date but I need the past date as well because I am trying to compare past forecasts to each other. Make sense?

Comment: That isn't consumable: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I have added a link to the data as an example. It is not a screenshot anymore. Hope this helps